# DISTINCT is not working as needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query and I need to show data with distinct id

```
 Query= "SELECT * FROM (" &_

 " SELECT DISTINCT t.TICKET_ID as TICKET_ID, "&_
 " ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.TICKET_ID DESC)NUM,"&_
" t.SHORT_DESCRIPTION as SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "&_
" p.TITLE as product_name"&_
" FROM T_TICKET as t,T_USER_PRODUCT as up "&_
" ,T_USER as u, T_PRODUCT as p" & _
 pReleaseFrom & _
" WHERE u.USER_ID=t.EDITOR_ID  AND not t.SHORT_DESCRIPTION is null" & _
 StateCondition & _

" ) A"& _   
" WHERE NUM BETWEEN " & Session("Start") & " AND " & Session("Endi")
Query=Query & " ORDER BY "&orderBy
```

but some rows are not distinct , and it 's not even making the order by t.TICKET_ID DESC.

Any help please ?

Comment: What is the result of this string concatenation? Is it the reason for the non-working sql? If not, it just distracts us from the core issue.

Comment: wich string exactly ? if you mean pReleaseFrom, it's a from table that i get from a combobox depending on what the user chooses

Comment: it gives the tickets, some not ordered and also duplicated, although i made  distinct and order by

Comment: I think what @Tim is asking is that when you post a question regarding a query, eliminate the extraneous information. Give us _just the query you actually execute_. For example, why should we care that you put it into a variable named `Query`? But more importantly, we don't know what is in the variable `orderBy` or `StateCondition` or `pReleaseFrom` so we can't really understand the query.

Comment: StateCondition is a condition on my state column which is choosen from the user, pReleaseFrom is a table that is set depending on what the user chose as a state condition

Comment: @kryptong: so why don't you show us the complete query without the (i presume)`VB.NET` code? You should tell us also the datatypes of all related tables' columns.

Comment: DISTINCT applies to everything in the SELECT. The "duplicate" records you are seeing must be different in some subtle way, for example, the description might be different - also since Row_Number is in there, and that tends to be a unique value I'd be surprised if the returns from this query are any different to an identical one without the DISTINCT.

Comment: So much string concatenation. Aren't we in 2014 now?

Comment: As there are only four output columns, could you please also (together with the actual SQL code not VB.NET code) provide with the returned rows that are deemed to be duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is in:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.TICKET_ID DESC) NUM
```

When you select all rownumbers, they are numbers like 1,2,3,4,5 and by design they are distinct. So it is no point to `SELECT DISTINCT` from distinct row numbers. Suppose that `TICKET_ID` is a unique primary key.

Another thing is that you possibly have a problem in the part:

```
FROM T_TICKET as t, T_USER_PRODUCT as up ,T_USER as u, T_PRODUCT as p
```

There you are actually doing `CROSS JOIN`- I am not sure if it is by design.

Also generating SQL command the way you do it is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. You should use parametrized query instead.

Answer (score 0):

"[The DISTINCT keyword eliminates duplicate **rows** from the results of a SELECT statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)". This means that if you do a SELECT DISTINCT, no duplicate **rows** will appear in your resultset. The row is viewed in its entirety to determine whether rows are distinct, not to one specific column in a row as you seem to think.